# How to pass huge array from Python to exe file

Tags: python, subprocess

Hi  I am trying to pass huge array from Python to exe file . However it doesnt work propely. Actually i have just found how to pass string arguments. But how can I send array[1000] elemnts. Please help

```
import subprocess

p =  random.uniform(1.5, 1.9)


subprocess.call(['ConsoleApplication9.exe', '176777777777777777777777'])
```

Comment: What does the `ConsoleApplication9.exe` expect as arguments? Just a large series of numbers, like this: `ConsoleApplication9.exe 1 2 34 56 765`?

Comment: it is my example which I have found . I need to pass huge array instead of this like float[10000]

Comment: The problem that I have no clue how to do this. because in this example the second argument is string. So I cant pass Object or anything,

Comment: Please clarify by providing a valid example of how to call the .exe application with multiple arguments. If you don't know this, then we can't help.

Comment: exe application lets assume test.exe. I want to call it from Python subprocess.call(['test.exe']). But I need to pass argument as huge array with 100000 elements like float[10000]. How i can do this i dont know

Comment: it works with  string arguments but i need to pass object as a huge array

Comment: But that's the problem, you can't call a program with 10000 arguments. YOu might be able to pipe them in on stdin, that's why people are asking.

Comment: yes =). Could you advise me how to do it please. Thats the problem

Comment: I tryed to find out how to pipe but unsuccessfully.

Comment: okay, i've updated with an example of piping to stdin.

Comment: a thousand elements is not huge unless individual elements are large. What is the element type? What do you mean by `array` is it a Python list, numpy array, `array.array`?

Answer (score 2):

Command arguments are always strings and they need to be in the format expected by the application being called. You can convert your array to strings, but its much too large for the command line and is it even the form the application wants?

Anyway, you could do:

```
# create a 10000 element array
array = [random.uniform(1.5, 1.9) for _ in range(10000)]
# try the call
subprocess.call(['ConsoleApplication9.exe'] + [str(d) for d in array])
```

But it won't work because the command line is too long for the system.

An alternate is to use the python struct module to pack the floats into a binary representation readable by the app and pump them into its stdin. The app will need to be written to read them from stdin.

```
import struct
import subprocess
import random

array = [random.uniform(1.5, 1.9) for _ in range(10000)]
proc = subprocess.Popen(['ConsoleApplication9.exe'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
for item in array:
    proc.stdin.write(struct.pack('f', item))
proc.stdin.close()
proc.wait()
```

Comment: Thanks  very much ! it is already something.

Answer (score 0):

```
subprocess.call(['ConsoleApplication9.exe', *array])
```